# How do I prevent both my if statements running the first time?

Tags: javascript

Quick question as I'm drawing a blank, if I have an event listener that contains 2 if statements that on first time round are both true but I don't want both of them to execute how do I prevent this? Can I break on the first conditional or something like that?

**JS**

```
var input = document.querySelector('.js-input'),
    output = document.querySelector('.js-output');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
        console.log('run this once');
    }

    if (this.value === '') {
        console.log('this is empty so show hint')
    }
});
```

Comment: Put else if condition..

Comment: You could use `else` between both `if`, or add a boolean variable `initialized`

Comment: out of interest, in what situation do you see only one of these statements being true?

Comment: @Rhumborl when the value has at least one character in it the first if will run, if the characters are all deleted the second if should run as the input is empty. My problem is that at the start both of these conditions are true. I'm also not sure of a better way?

Comment: either nest them, or use "else if"

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = document.querySelector('.js-input'),
    output = document.querySelector('.js-output');
var firstTimeCallbackRun= true;

input.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
        console.log('run this once');
        if(firstTimeCallbackRun) {
          firstTimeCallbackRun = false;
          return;
        }
    }

    if (this.value === '') {
        console.log('this is empty so show hint')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('.js-input'),
    output = document.querySelector('.js-output'),
    isFirst = true;

input.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (isFirst) {
      isFirst = false;
      return;
    }
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
        console.log('run this once');
    }

    if (this.value === '') {
        console.log('this is empty so show hint')
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, I want the first if statement to run on keydown but not the second. This prevents everything on first?\

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that? But probably you should ask yourself why this is happening and what are you doing wrong. Since it is a hacky and not optimal solution.

```
(function() {
    var firstRun = true;

    var input = document.querySelector('.js-input');
    var output = document.querySelector('.js-output');

    input.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (firstRun) {
            firstRun = false;

            if (this.value.length === 0) {
                console.log('run this once');
            }
        } else {
            if (this.value === '') {
                console.log('this is empty so show hint')
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Here an [example](http://jsbin.com/tedezenuqi/1/edit?js,output) of how you could achieve this:

```
(function() {
  var input = document.querySelector('.js-input');

  var isDirty = function(element) {
    if ( ! element.data) {
        element.data = {isDirty: false};
    }

    if (element.value.length > 0 && ! element.data.isDirty) {
        element.data.isDirty = true;
    } else if (element.value.length === 0) {
        element.data.isDirty = false;
    }

    return element.data.isDirty;
  };

  input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    var dirtyClass = " is-dirty";

    if (isDirty(this)) {
      if (this.className.search(dirtyClass) === -1) {
        this.className += dirtyClass; 
      }
    } else {
      this.className = this.className.replace(dirtyClass, "");
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Hey, can you advise how you would make this better? I'm not sure how to deal with this in a better way

Comment: If you precisely describe what your requirements are, I could help you.

Comment: Thanks, so when the user starts adding text to the input I want to add a class .is-dirty to the input so as soon as a character is added I guessed it would be ok just to run this once. Then if the user deletes all the input text I want to remove the class .is-dirty so I'm checking if the value is empty?

Comment: @styler sorry for the late answer, i've created an example for you.